# Any way for users to communicate a parameter to an Android application?

Tags: android

In Android Live Wallpapers, the usual Android View classes cannot be used (as far as I know). Therefore, if you want to let a user select a file, you would have to write your own File Chooser interface pixel by pixel. This would be an extraordinary endeavor.

Is there any way for users to pass a parameter -- such as a file name or directory location -- to an Android application?

Comment: Why not let them use an existing file manager (or pop up text box to enter the path), when the live wallpaper is first set up, then store the given value in a database, or somewhere else on the file system, and retrieve that when you need the value?

Answer (score 2):

Live Wallpapers have a mechanism to have a settings UI associated with them that can be set when the user is selecting the wallpaper.  This is android:settingsActivity described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Wallpaper

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Open Intents. For example, apps like [OI File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager&hl=en) offer intents like PICK_FILE that let other app developers use their functionality. Installing may add several clicks the first time but it's otherwise fairly seamless (just like choosing an attachment from Gmail).

Check out:

- [Open Intents: Pick Folder](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/357)
- [Open Intents: Pick File](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/164)